# Does Ford-Fulkerson always produce the left-most min-cut

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

When using Ford-Fulkerson to find max-flow between s and t, the exact choice of flow-graph depends on which paths are found.

However, if you then use the left-over residual graph to produce a min-cut (by flood-filling outward from s along any edges or reverse edges with left-over capacity), it seems the same cut is obtained regardless of which flow-graph you use.

Is this true?

Is there a way to iterate over all cuts such that each iterator-step requires only polynomial time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Ford-Fulkerson always finds the cut that is "closest" to the source.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29418244/781723) for a formalization of what is meant by "closest".

A graph can contain exponentially many min-cuts, so beware that any procedure to enumerate all min-cuts must take exponential time in total in the worst case.

Based on what I've read, there are output-sensitive algorithms to enumerate all min $(s,t)$-cuts.  After a single maximum flow computation, the running time is $O(n)$ per min-cut that is output.  Details can be found in the following paper:

Jean-Claude Picard, Maurice Queyranne.  [On the structure of all minimum cuts in a network and applications](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01581031).  Combinatorial Optimization II: Mathematical Programming Studies, volume 13, 1980, pp.8--16.
<sup>Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a non-paywalled online version of the paper.</sup>

(See also [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16466/5038) for a related question.)

---

In contrast, if you want to find all min-cuts of an undirected graph, rather than all min $(s,t)$-cuts, you can [use Karger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm#Finding_all_min-cuts) to do that efficiently (in polynomial time).

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the answer of [D.W.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/42962/107966). Following is a simple example of a graph network that contains an exponential number of $(s,t)$ min cuts.

Let the vertex set be $V = \{s\} \cup \{u_{1},\dotsc,u_{n}\} \cup \{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\} \cup \{t\}$. Let the edges set contains the directed edges $(s,u_{i})$, $(u_{i},v_{i})$, and $(v_{i},t)$ for each $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$. Therefore, there are total $3 n$ edges. Each edge has capacity $1$.

The max-flow on this network is $n$.

The min-cut cut obtained using Ford-Fulkerson algorithm is $\left(\{s\}, V \setminus \{s\}\right)$.

There are other $(s,t)$ min cuts in the graph as follows. Let $C = (S,T)$ be a cut such that $S$ contains the vertex $s$ and all the vertices in the set $\{u_1,\dotsc,u_n\}$. It is optional to include a vertex $v_{i}$ in the set $S$.  The remaining vertices, i.e.,  $V \setminus S$ belongs to $T$. Any such cut has a capacity $n$. Therefore, it is a min-cut. Since there are $2^n$ choices of including $v_{i}'s$, the total number of min-cuts are $2^n \in 2^{O|V|}$. Hence, we get an exponential number of min-cuts.