# How to find all minimum cuts in network flow

Tags: network-flow, ford-fulkerson

In a network flow graph, using the Ford–Fulkerson algorithm, we can find a residual graph `G_f` which no [augmenting paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network#Augmenting_paths). This gives us a way of finding **one** minimum cut (a cut `(S, T)` with minimum capacity) where `S` is the set of vertices reachable from the source vertex `s` in `G_f` (and it is clear that this set of vertices are not in `T`, the cut that is on the side of the sink vertex `t`).

Analogously, we can repeat the Ford–Fulkerson algorithm to find a residual graph `G'_f` that is anchored at the sink `t`, such that we can find **another** minimum cut `(S', T')` where `T'` is the set of vertices reachable from the sink vertex `t` in `G'_f`. It is possible that `(S, T)` and `(S', T')` are different (see my made-up network flow below with 2 different minimum cuts):

[image]

The question there is, is there are more comprehensive way of finding other minimum cuts in the the flow network? Or are there only ever a maximum of 2 minimum cuts in a flow network?

Comment: In the above link, I have added a [simple example](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/140310/107966) of a flow network that contains an exponential number of min-cuts.